# Curve function in R for non-standard normal distribution

Tags: r

How can I use the curve function in R to draw a normal distribution curve by passing the mean and standard deviation? Not a standard normal curve, but by passing mu and sigma.

Answer (score 4):

```
curve({ dnorm(x, mean=1,sd=.5)}, -2,2)
```